# Empty and append to closest DIV

Tags: jquery

I've put together a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Rockhopper92/zrq5L2dj/

My problem is trying to find the closest div and empty then append into it. My understanding is that closest only finds parent elements but I'm unsure as to why this is not finding it.

I have tried moving the elements around but this obviously disrupts the toggle working.

**My jQuery looks like this:**

```
$(".subscribedTo").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var labelText = "Subscribed";
  } else {
    var labelText = "Unsubscribed";
  }
  $(this).closest(".labelText").empty();
});
```

**And the HTML affected is this:**

```
<div class="block">
  <label class="label">
  <div class="toggle">
    <input class="subscribedTo" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" checked>
    <div class="toggle-inner">
       <div class="indicator"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="labelText">Subscribed</div>
</label>
</div>
```

I'm unsure what I can do to identify the labelText div with that jQuery and append to it as there will be multiple divs with the same class value on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is that `closest()` looks for parent elements, yet the `.labelText` element you're aiming for is a sibling of the checkbox. As such you can either use `siblings()` or `closest().find()`, personally I prefer the latter as it's more robust.

Also note that you can provide a function to `text()` to set the new value based on the state of the `checked` property of the checkbox. You don't need to do the `empty()` and append as separate calls. Try this:

```js
$(".subscribedTo").on("click", function() {
  var checkbox = this;
  $(this).closest('.block').find(".labelText").text(function() {
    return checkbox.checked ? 'Subscribed' : 'Unsubscribed';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <label class="label">
    <div class="toggle">
      <input class="subscribedTo" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" checked>
      <div class="toggle-inner">
         <div class="indicator"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="labelText">Subscribed</div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, makes sense and well written thanks Rory :)